# Making collapse with slider in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular9

I am working on angular project. I am trying to make a collapse. My code is as follows

```
 <div class="myClass">
            <mat-accordion>
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                      <mat-panel-title>
                      </mat-panel-title>
                      <mat-panel-description>
                         Description           
                      </mat-panel-description>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  </mat-expansion-panel>
              </mat-accordion>
        </div>

.myClass {
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: auto;
}

 .mat-expansion-panel-header {
      width: 99.7vw;
  }

   .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
      flex-grow: 1;
  }
```

Reason for using `margin-top:auto` because I want this collapse at end of page. Once I click on collapse icon my collapse should open and it should look like as shown in image[image: myquestion]

Once my collapse open I want to have these types of card with my data and on opening of this collapse I want to 4-5 boxes/cards in row as shown but in case if more data is present then I want to slide using ">>" and show these box/cards. If I click "<<" on left hand side then it should move in that direction. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a carousel. Not the easiest of things to do if you're new to angular. I would recommend just using owl carousel. There's an [angular wrapper](https://github.com/vitalii-andriiovskyi/ngx-owl-carousel-o#readme) you can use. Or if you want to make a carousel on your own you can follow this [guide](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/angular-animations-lets-create-a-carousel-with-reusable-animations-81c0dd8847e8).

For the collapsing of the carousel, you'd have to make a button that switches collapse state. Something like this-

```
    <button (click)="collapsed = !collapsed"></button>
    <div *ngIf="!collapsed" >
        <carousel-component></carousel-component>
    <div>
```